# Tensorflow - Accuracy begins at 1.0 and decreases with loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN on 10K grayscale images. The network has 6 conv layers, 1 fully connect layer and 1 output layer.

When i begin training the loss in insanely high but steadily decreases, but my accuracy starts off at 1.0 and decreases also. and fluctuates from like 72% down to 30% and back up again. Also, when i run `acc.eval({x: test_images, y: test_lables})` on unseen images, the accuracy is at about 16%.

Also, I have 6 classes all of which are one-hot encoded.

I think i may be comparing the predicted output incorrectly but cant see the error in my code...

Here is my code

```
pred = convolutional_network(x)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = pred))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)

prediction = tf.nn.softmax(pred)
correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # Initialize all the variables
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    time_full_start = time.clock()
    print("RUNNING SESSION...")
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_batch_x = []
        train_batch_y = []
        epoch_loss = 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(images):
            start = i
            end = i+ batch_size
            train_batch_x = images[start:end]
            train_batch_y = labels[start:end]
            op , ac, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, acc, loss], feed_dict={x: train_batch_x, y: train_batch_y})
            epoch_loss += loss_value
            i += batch_size
        print('Epoch : ', epoch+1, ' of ', num_epochs, ' - Loss for epoch: ', epoch_loss, ' Accuracy: ', ac)

    time_full_end = time.clock()
    print('Full time elapse:', time_full_end - time_full_start)


    print('Accuracy:', acc.eval({x: test_images, y: test_labels}))

    save_path = saver.save(sess, MODEL_PATH)
    print("Model saved in file: " , save_path)
```

And here is the outputs

```
Epoch :  1  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  8.94737603121e+13  Accuracy:  1.0

Epoch :  2  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  212052447727.0  Accuracy:  1.0

Epoch :  3  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  75150603462.2  Accuracy:  1.0

Epoch :  4  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  68164116617.4  Accuracy:  1.0

Epoch :  5  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  18505190718.8  Accuracy:  0.99

Epoch :  6  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  11373286689.0  Accuracy:  0.96

Epoch :  7  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  3129798657.75  Accuracy:  0.07

Epoch :  8  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  374790121.375  Accuracy:  0.58

Epoch :  9  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  105383792.938  Accuracy:  0.72

Epoch :  10  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  49705202.4844  Accuracy:  0.66

Epoch :  11  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  30214170.7909  Accuracy:  0.36

Epoch :  12  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  18653020.5084  Accuracy:  0.82

Epoch :  13  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  14793638.35  Accuracy:  0.39

Epoch :  14  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  10196079.7003  Accuracy:  0.73

Epoch :  15  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  6727522.37319  Accuracy:  0.47

Epoch :  16  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  4593769.05838  Accuracy:  0.68

Epoch :  17  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  3669332.09406  Accuracy:  0.44

Epoch :  18  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  2850924.81662  Accuracy:  0.59

Epoch :  19  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  1780678.12892  Accuracy:  0.51

Epoch :  20  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  1855037.40652  Accuracy:  0.61

Epoch :  21  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  1012934.52827  Accuracy:  0.53

Epoch :  22  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  649319.432669  Accuracy:  0.55

Epoch :  23  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  841660.786938  Accuracy:  0.57

Epoch :  24  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  490148.861691  Accuracy:  0.55

Epoch :  25  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  397315.021568  Accuracy:  0.5

 ......................

Epoch :  99  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  4412.61703086  Accuracy:  0.57

Epoch :  100  of  100  - Loss for epoch:  4530.96991658  Accuracy:  0.62

Full time elapse: 794.5787720000001

**Test Accuracy: 0.158095**
```

I have experimented with multiple learning rates and network sizes, but can seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should randomize the order data is feed into your neural network. Also, are there any errors in the data? Specificity are you sure that every class has exactly 1 binary value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note, my answer is also informed by having reviewed and debugged the full code (not visible in the question.) Still I believe the issues below are general enough to be worthy of review if someone is facing a similar issue - you might just get the solution here!

---

The insanely high loss values could mean that you didn't convert the input images from **int8** to small **float32** values properly (in fact, he did) and you don't use batch normalization and/or regularization either (in fact, both were missing.) Also, in this code:

```
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(pred)
correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
```

calculating the softmax value is completely unnecessary, because softmax is a strictly monotonous function, it only scales the prediction, the largest value in `pred` will be the largest is `prediction`, you get the same result by

```
correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
```

Given the insanely high values your network operates at, it's possible that `tf.nn.softmax()` when does the exponentiation and division by the sum, it inadvertently reduces everything to zero, and then `tf.argmax()` just picks class 0 until the numbers come down a little. Add to that that you don't cumulate `ac`:

```
op , ac, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, acc, loss], feed_dict={x: train_batch_x, y: train_batch_y})
```

so the `epoch accuracy` you're printing is not that, it's just the accuracy from the last batch. If your images are class-ordered and you don't randomize the batch, then you might get class zero images at the end of each epoch. That would explain why you get 100% accuracy *in the first few epochs*, until the super high numbers come down a bit and softmax doesn't zero everything any more. (This in fact turned out the be the case.)

Even after fixing the above, the network didn't learn anything at all. As it turned out, when he added randomization, the images and labels were randomized differently, resulting naturally in a constant ***1 / 6*** accuracy.

Having fixed all the issues, the network was able to learn to 98% accuracy on this task after 100 epochs.

> Epoch: 100/100 loss: 6.20184610883 total loss: 25.4021390676 acc: 97.976191%

Comment: Hi peter thanks for getting back to me.. i have randomized the images and labels which did reduce the insanely high loss values and prevented the 100% accuracy when starting training,  

and have fixed the code so it is printing the overall accuracy for each epoch (not the last batch) thanks for pointing that one out... 

As of now, i can only get the loss down to ~150.00, 
Would i be able to send you the jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes, please do. Also the data you use.

Comment: Thank you @PeterSzoldan In my case, I had to change the input type from int8 to float32. Only then did model start behaving sanely. Thus, the data type really matters.